# Macro workbook.open crash excel

Tags: excel, vba

In my excel file I have macro:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

End Sub
```

It causes that when  I open a file excel crash...

[image: Screen]

When I remove this macro, everything is ok.

Do You have any idea what could be a reason?
Thank You in advance

Win 7,
Excel 2013

Comment: Does that macro contains any other lines of code?

Comment: No, I remove all lines and problem still exist.

Comment: Is this macro contained in the `ThisWorkbook` object?

Comment: Yes. Is there any way to run macro while opening file?

Comment: Normally yes. Can you try to put that macro in a new file to see if Excel still crashes?

Comment: I new file there is no error. What could be the reason if the macro is empty and do nothing?

Answer (score 1):

If the problem does not occur with a new workbook, this could be due to some naming conflicts or some similar problem inside the VBA Project.

You may try to compile your code to see if anything turns up.

[image: Debug Compile VBA Project]

Comment: It partially help. Empty makro do not make an error. But if I add anything (even Activesheet.Range("A1").Select or msgbox("Hi")) it crashes again...

Comment: Without more information about the file, it's hard to know.

Comment: I add that file works on several computers, crash only on a few.

Comment: Try https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2015/06/excel-crashes-when-enabling-macros/ and if it does not work try to change safty options in Options -> Safety Center -> Macro Settings (enable for example Trust access to the VBA object model)

Comment: Unfortunately does not help.

Answer (score 0):

What helps,

My file has several spreadsheets. Size of the file was around 3mb. 
I have deleted all unnecessary spreadsheets what change filesize to 1mb and problem disapeared.

I do not change anything in VBA code.